# Angular 2 unit test for NgModule class

Tags: unit-testing, angular

Wanted to know if there is any way to make NgModule class unit testable.

If yes want can we expect in test case it block.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import
       { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: There is usually no behaviour in an `NgModule` to unit test, use integration/E2E testing to make sure the modules all work together correctly.

Comment: Good question, I like to test if the module imports all necessary modules and the components just render fine in the app later in the build process. Does anyone a way to unit test this? (nowadays using Angular10)